# Why does Windows VPN MS-CHAP v2 map error code 649 to 812?

Tags: vpn, l2tp

When attempting to make a Windows VPN connection with MS-CHAP v2, why is error 649 mapped to the much more generic error 812? The former would seem to be much more useful.

The dialog box shown to the user displays error 812, but this snippet from svchost_RASCHAP.LOG. *appears* to show that the server actually returned code 649.

```
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: ChapMakeMessage,RBuf=00000000081213E2
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: ChapCMakeMessage...
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: CS_ResponseSent
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: Message received...
04 00 00 0E 45 3D 36 34 39 20 52 3D 30 20 00 00 |....E=649 R=0 ..|
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: Failure received...
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: GetInfoFromFailure...
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: RASDiag: Mapping to new error code: 812 (ERROR_SERVER_POLICY) instead of 649 (ERROR_NO_DIALIN_PERMISSION)
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: GetInfoFromFailure done,e=812,r=0,v=2
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: Auth failed for unknown reaons with no Retry :| error=812 retry-count=0
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: Done :(
[3084] 03-30 18:26:00:462: ChapEnd
```

Comment: Do you want to know why, or do you want to diagnose the error with your connection? We cannot answer "why" questions here, because the correct answer is just "because". But we're happy to help you find a solution to a problem.

Comment: I was hoping for some expertise on why a specific error code would be made less specific by the client before display. The admin on the other side fixed the issue with my connection, so I'm OK. He didn't tell me how he fixed it.

Comment: Because he was the one who fixed it, you'd have to ask him. Someone may possibly know what is going on just from looking at the log, but there is a very good chance the logs and information on the host contain more information necessary to answer the question.